# Python - I can’t import openCV module in replit.com

Tags: python, opencv, replit

I’m working with replit.com in python, and i can’t import the openCV module.
When i do this :
`import cv2`

I have that error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File
"main. py"
, line 2, in module>
import cv2
File
"/home/runner/rickRolledInConsole/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.
init
.py", line 181, in
<module>
bootstrap()
File
"/home/runner/rickRolledInConsole/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/
init
_.py"
, line 111, in bootstrap
load_first_config(['config.py'],True)
File"/home/runner/rickRolledInConsole/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cv2/.
init
•py", line 109, in load_first_config
raise ImportError( 'OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {J. Check Open
CV installation.'.format(fnames))
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check Ope
CV installation.
```

This may be from REPLIT, but if you have a solution, I'm taking
Thanks

Comment: try `pip install --upgrade opencv-python
pip install --upgrade pyinstaller`

Comment: The installation works but the same error occurs

Comment: please seek user support for replit from the replit company

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any direct solution for this but you can do your project by forking another repl that doesn't have this kind of problem,here's a repl that you can fork and continue your project.
[openCV tutorial repl](https://replit.com/@Frankwin/openCv-tutorial)

Answer (score 0):

This import worked for me:

```
python -m poetry add opencv-python==4.5.3.56
```